# Is it possible to use \pause without using beamer?

Tags: beamer, macros, templates, pause

I'm learning how to design templates and configure the layout further, and I thought it could be a good idea to build a template for "presentations" without beamer. (because I think it's easier to resemble a whiteboard with it)

What I'm trying to figure out is how to use something similar to `\pause` without necessarily using beamer.

- How would I achieve that behavior?
- Is this something too crazy?

Comment: there are more complicated aswers, but "no" is the most reasonable answer.

Comment: If you use beamer without a theme, it very much resembles an whiteboard.

Comment: `beamer` goes to some lengths to implement `\pause` and friends, and while it's certainly doable (as a last resort to just copy that implementation), don't expect something like that to be an easy undertaking.

Comment: What about the font?
Where can I get information on how to use beamer without a template?
In the manual?

Comment: Maybe you are searching `frame` option `plain` (see chapter 8 of the manual) to have frames without title etc.

Comment: @ekiim Just use `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}` No need to load a theme.

Comment: @ekiim  You can put a button on every page of a pdf, pointing to the next page and vice versa and you can have slides without Beamer, but if you have a Porsche, why do you need a VW?